# Power Pivot - Count cells that contain specific text?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, powerpivot

I keep trying but I would appreciate some help.

How do I do this https://exceljet.net/formula/count-cells-that-contain-specific-text
But with a PowerPivot?

I need this but in Power Pivot: `=COUNTIF(rng,"*"&a1&"*")`

I would be very grateful for any help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you add some sample data and show how your formula is used - is it on every row of the table?  Is A2 in the table?

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks a lot for looking at it. I updated my question to put an example. Thanks again.

Comment: I edited again my question to keep it simple.

Comment: I still dont get where a1 comes from.  Is it user input? In the table?

Comment: A simple solution could be just a simple count, and use the Pivot Table row filtering e.g. Label Filters / Contains.